# spring security: custom messages for different types of disabled used

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

let's say user can be disabled because he hasn't clicked on the email verification link, he hasn't payed for the service, he hasn't setup 2FA etc. i need a way of delivering user different message for different reason.

when i use subclass of `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` i can only set `enabled = false` and spring will provide some default message.

other option i tried is to implement `UserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername` and then throw any exception with any message but then i have to fine tune error logging mechanism to prevent logging those exceptions so i assume that's not the spring's way of doing this.

what's the spring's way of handling this scenario?

Comment: As a starting point register a failure handler and then write the relevant response to the HttpServletResponse output stream based on the exception type. https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.12.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationFailureHandler.html. I'm guessing you could also register a handler per concrete exception type. See example at: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-authentication-failure-handler

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the best way would be to augment the authentication provider by adding additional authentication checks, throwing appropriate exceptions and then writing a handler for those exceptions.

We can extend [DaoAuthenticationProvider](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/DaoAuthenticationProvider.html) and use its [additionalAuthenticationChecks(...)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/DaoAuthenticationProvider.html#additionalAuthenticationChecks-org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails-org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken-) method.

We can throw any custom exception or an exception that is caught by the appropriate token granter. Here's a sample example:

```
@Override
protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(final UserDetails userDetails, final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) {
    final User user = userDao.findByUsername(userDetails.getUsername())
                             .orElseThrow(() -> new BadCredentialsException("Incorrect username or password."));

    if (DISABLED == user.getStatus() || SUSPENDED == user.getStatus()) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException(String.format("User account with ID [%s] is %s.", user.getUserUuid(), user.getStatus()));
    }

    if (2FA_NOT_SET == user.getStatus()) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Account is disabled because two-factor authentication is not set.");
    }
```

In this example, [ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/password/ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter.html) will catch BadCredentialsException and throw InvalidGrantException (child of OAuth2Exception).

We can then write our custom exception handler by extending [ResponseEntityExceptionHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.html). Here we can log the exception and prepare a custom error response. Here's a sample code for reference:

```
@ExceptionHandler({OAuth2Exception.class})
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleOAuth2Exception(final OAuth2Exception exception, final WebRequest request) {

    return handleExceptionInternal(exception,
                                   ErrorOutputDto.create(exception.getOAuth2ErrorCode(), exception.getMessage()),
                                   new HttpHeaders(),
                                   HttpStatus.valueOf(exception.getHttpErrorCode()),
                                   request);
}
```